# How to use the uiimagepickercontroller in uitabbar?

Tags: iphone

iam developing one application.In that i use uitabbar with 5 tabs and another uitabbar with 4 tabs.And inbetween these two tabs i place the that each tab view.Below code i use for place the tab view for one uitabbar

- (void)tabBar:(UITabBar *)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem *)item
  {

  if(item.tag==0)
  {

  ```
         UIViewController *chkin = [viewController objectAtIndex:0];
  [self.selectedViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
  chkin.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,88, 320,323);
  [self.view addSubview:chkin.view];
  self.selectedViewController = chkin;
  [chkin release];
  ```

}

else

if(item.tag==1)

{

```
        UIViewController *chkService = [viewController objectAtIndex:1];
        [self.selectedViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
        chkService.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,88, 320,323);
        [self.view addSubview:chkService.view];
        self.selectedViewController = chkService;
        [chkService release];
    }
    else 
        if(item.tag==2)
        {

            UIViewController *chkDecor = [viewController objectAtIndex:2];
            [self.selectedViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
            chkDecor.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,88, 320,323);
            [self.view addSubview:chkDecor.view];
            self.selectedViewController = chkDecor;
            [chkDecor release];
        }
        else 
            if(item.tag==3)
            {

                UIViewController *chkStaff = [viewController objectAtIndex:3];
                [self.selectedViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                chkStaff.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,88, 320,323);
                [self.view addSubview:chkStaff.view];
                self.selectedViewController = chkStaff;
                [chkStaff release];

            }
            else 
                if(item.tag==4)
                {
                    UIViewController *chkNotes = [viewController objectAtIndex:4];
                    [self.selectedViewController.view removeFromSuperview];
                    chkNotes.view.frame=CGRectMake(0,88, 320,323);
                    [self.view addSubview:chkNotes.view];
                    self.selectedViewController = chkNotes;
                    [chkNotes release];

                }
```

}

But the main problem is.In that one tab contain the table.Each cell contain the imageview for taking the image from camera.Forthat i written the code like

- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
  didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
  {

  UIImage* image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

  NSLog(@"image selected");
   itemimageview.image =image;
  [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

}
when iam execute this one the image will be appear for last cell imageview only.And that tab view hides the below tabbar.So please tell me how to manage the imagepicker with uitabbar.